# Access output from Json to success function ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-8

I have trouble on how to display the output of my json into success, by writing `+response+` it will display [object Object]. The output will change based on id, so i think i dont need to use foreach? :/

View:-

```
function getItemDetails(item_id){

$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url: './itemDetails/'+item_id,
    datatype: 'json',

    success: function(response){
      console.log(response);
      $('#modalTitle').text("TITLE");
      $('#variants-area-inside').append('<label class="form-control-label">'+response+'</label>');
    }
 });
}
```

Console output:-

```
{
  "data": {
    "name": "Fried Chicken Wings",
    "id": 99,
    "extras": [],
    "options": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "item_id": 99,
        "name": "Size",
        "options": "small,medium"
      }
    ],
    "variants": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "price": 13,
        "options": "{\"1\":\"small\"}",
        "item_id": 99,
       }
    ],
    "has_variants": true,
    "description": "Fried Chicken Wings"
  }
}
```

Comment: Whether you need `forEach()` or not depends on what output you're trying to create - can you edit the question to include an example of this. You will at least need to output the properties values of the object, or their child arrays, not the object as a whole (which is why you see the current output).

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time using ajax and i don't really get what you mean :/

Comment: I mean, can you edit the question to show the HTML output you're expecting to see instead of the `[Object object]` string

Comment: Okay, updated! I want to output the options..

Comment: No, that's an image of the HTML. Please add the *acutal HTML by copying and pasting it*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
function getItemDetails(item_id){

$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url: './itemDetails/'+item_id,
    datatype: 'json',

    success: function(response){
      console.log(response);
      $('#modalTitle').text("TITLE");
      response.data.options.forEach(option => {
          $('#variants-area-inside').append('<label class="form-control-label">' + option.options+'</label>');
      });
    }
 });
}
```

Comment: Does this mean i need to use foreach? Let say i want to get the output of Fried Chicken Wings name, how do I do that?

Comment: @cdogol That would be `response.data.name`. You need `forEach` only, if you want to access properties in the `options` array.

Comment: But why everytime i click on it, the output will keep adding. I've attached the image on the question :/

Comment: I don't know, where you are clicking. If every click executes your getItemDetails() function, then it will keep adding.